# Gson ignoring map entries with value=null

Tags: java, json, gson

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("a", 1);
map.put("b", null);

System.out.println(gson.toJson(map)); //prints {"a":1}
```

How do I get it to include all entries?

Answer (score 344, accepted):

See [Gson User Guide - Null Object Support](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Null-Object-Support):

> The default behaviour that is implemented in Gson is that null object fields are ignored. This allows for a more compact output format; however, the client must define a default value for these fields as the JSON format is converted back into its Java form.
>
> Here's how you would configure a Gson instance to output null:
>
> ```
> Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
> ```

Comment: The manual should be more optimized for searching. I'm not going to read everything when I use a small amount of feats. This was the first result on google. Fixed my issue.

Comment: @MathijsSegers Some of the fantastic libraries are without documentation. Having so much trouble going through their source code (which is again with lot of builder patterns and all).

Comment: @MathijsSegers And this is the beauty of SO and Google. I can google "gson ignore null" and find this answer in 3 seconds instead of having to find the manual and an answer in it.

Comment: How to include only one NULL field not all NULL fields inside class? Is there an Annotation I can add above the required field?

Comment: this solution seems reasonable and I did expect it to work! but it doesn't! any ideas?