# Retrofit null\empty Date handling

Tags: android, date, exception, retrofit, pojo

I've got Date field in my POJO and I use retrofit to parse JSON. In some cases returning value of this field can be empty or null. And I get error:

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "" (at offset 0)
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:618)
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:105)
```

Is there any smart way to handle this exception with retrofit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register a custom  `Deserializer`  for the `Date` class

```
GsonBuilder gBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() { .... }
Gson gSon = gBuilder.create();
```

when the callback is invoked, check the content of the `JsonElement` before formatting the date, and act accordingly.

Don't forget to call `addConverterFactory` with the Gson instance you created. Eg

```
 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gSon))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add Gson please use this :

```
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

if you not adding the old retrofit should look like:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'")
            .create();

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .build();
```

Please take a look at :
[GSON DOCS](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support)

And also I think there is a question very similar.

[Gson ignoring map entries with value=null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923759/gson-ignoring-map-entries-with-value-null)