# How to pass a key with null value or an empty String in the request body in retrofit android

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android

I need to pass the keys even with no values as the keys are mandatory at the server side. But Retrofit was removing the keys with null values while sending the request. How I can achieve sending keys without values to the server with the use of Retrofit?

Request body look like this :

```
{
        "first_name":"testlogin",
        "last_name":"lastname",
        "username":"testman", 
        "password":"test123", 
        "email":"tester@test.com", 
        "address1":"123+test+way",
        **"address2":"",**
        **"address3":"",**
        "postal_code":"75023",
        "country":1,
        **"state":""**
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An empty string is not a null value. Can you not `setState("")`, for example?

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 but Retrofit not sending keys with empty string value also...

Comment: Are you using the Gson converter?

Comment: yes, I am converting the model into string using Gson converter and sending it as Body... After Gson conversion string has the keys with empty strings. Above json object is after the conversion..

Comment: I haven't used Gson in a while, but my guess is that Gson is removing empty/null values from the JSON object, not Retrofit.

Comment: `Gson` is, indeed, removing the `null` values by default. This is a dangerous default, I find, I should be changed. For example, delete the value of a field on a mobile device and send to a JSON web service with Gson, and that field never gets emptied on the web service database. Not a good behaviour, by default. Probably more efficient, because it's not sending null records, but it's a surprising result.

Answer (score 28):

Try passing it as:

```
"address2":null,
"address3":null,
"postal_code":"75023"
"country":1,
"state":null
```

Since you are using Gson converter, try creating the gson as:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923759/gson-ignoring-map-entries-with-value-null).

Comment: I have same solution but another way for apply it.I am posting this comment because this may help someone. You can apply this in retrofit builder like this. `addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()))`

Comment: but I want to pass it for some particular request, not for all. then what should I use?