# How to serialize with Gson an object that defines variable with same name as variable inherited from parent

Tags: java, json, inheritance, gson

I want to write a new class that extends another, and in the new class I want to define a variable with the same name as one in the parent. I can do this fine in Java since both are private but when I try to serialize the object with gson I get an error since there are two properties with the same name (even if the one inherited from the parent class is null and therefore should not be included in the json).

For example consider these classes:

```
public class Car {
    private String color;
    private Seat seat;
}

public class Seat {
    private boolean isAdjustable;
}
```

and these classes:

```
public class FancyCar extends Car {
    private FancySeat seat;
    private boolean hasSpoiler;
}

public class Fancyseat extends Seat {
    private boolean hasSeatWarmers;
}
```

with these classes I could create a new FancyCar with a seat that isAdjustable and hasSeatWarmers. But if I were to serialize with gson it would throw an exception as it tries to parse both the variables named seat even if the one inherited from Car is null.

Is there a better way to design these classes? Or a way to tell gson to ignore null fields altogether?

Comment: not sure if this is your need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923805/4298881

Answer (score 0):

You can use @SerializedName(value = "fancySeat") Also, from Gson version.2.4 There is an option to alternate or have multiple name for serializedName when deserializing. No Need of CustomTypeadapter.
[Gson Field Naming](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)
[Example for Multiple deserialization names](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-model-annotations-multiple-deserialization-names-with-serializedname)

```
package com.test.practice;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class JsonSerializationExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Seat seatCar = new Seat();
    seatCar.setAdjustable(true);

    Fancyseat fancySeat = new Fancyseat();
    fancySeat.setHasSeatWarmers(true);
    fancySeat.setAdjustable(false);

    Car car = new Car();
    car.setColor("black");
    car.setSeat(seatCar);

    FancyCar fancyCar = new FancyCar();
    fancyCar.setColor("white");
    fancyCar.setSeat(fancySeat);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(fancyCar);
    System.out.println("json :: "+jsonString);  
  }

}

class Car {
private String color;
private Seat seat;
public String getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}
public Seat getSeat() {
    return seat;
}
public void setSeat(Seat seat) {
    this.seat = seat;
}

}

class Seat {
private boolean isAdjustable;

public boolean isAdjustable() {
    return isAdjustable;
}

public void setAdjustable(boolean isAdjustable) {
    this.isAdjustable = isAdjustable;
}

} 

 class FancyCar extends Car {

 @SerializedName(value = "fancySeat")
    private Fancyseat seat;
    private boolean hasSpoiler;
    public Fancyseat getSeat() {
        return seat;
    }
    public void setSeat(Fancyseat seat) {
        this.seat = seat;
    }
    public boolean isHasSpoiler() {
        return hasSpoiler;
    }
    public void setHasSpoiler(boolean hasSpoiler) {
        this.hasSpoiler = hasSpoiler;
    }

  }

 class Fancyseat extends Seat {
    private boolean hasSeatWarmers;

    public boolean isHasSeatWarmers() {
        return hasSeatWarmers;
    }

    public void setHasSeatWarmers(boolean hasSeatWarmers) {
        this.hasSeatWarmers = hasSeatWarmers;
    }


  }
```